# Show that $|\operatorname{Hom}_K(L,K^{alg})|\leq [L:K]$.

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ a field and $L/K$ a field extension. I denote $$\operatorname{Hom}_K(L,K^{alg})=\{\varphi: L\to K^{alg}\mid \varphi\text{  is  a field homomorphism s.t. }\varphi|_K=id_K\}$$
and $K^{alg}$ the field of algebraic element of $K$. I want to show that $$|\operatorname{Hom}_K(L,K^{alg})| \leq [L:K]$$
in the case where $L=K(x)$ for a certain $x\in K$.

**My attempts**

Let $x\in K$ and $P$ it's minimal polynomial (i.e. a monic irreducible polynomial s.t. $P(x)=0$ and minimal in the sense that if $Q(x)=0$ then $P(x)\mid Q(x)$.) I shaw that if $\sigma \in\operatorname{Hom}_K(L,K^{alg})$ then $\sigma (x)$ is also a root of $P$, then it looks obvious that $$|\operatorname{Hom}_K(L,K^{alg})|\leq [L:K]$$
but I have problem to write it properly.

Answer (score 0):

In one hand $$[L:K]\geq \deg P$$
in other hand for all $\sigma \in Hom(L,K^{alg})$, $\sigma (x)$ is a root. Therefore if $$g(X)=\prod_{\sigma \in Hom(L,K^{alg})}(X-\sigma (x))$$
then $$G(X)= P(X)$$ (since $G(X)\mid P(X)$ and thus, we have the equality by minimality of $P(X)$.)
Finally, you get $$|Hom(L,K^{alg})|=\deg(P)\leq [L:K].$$